# Taking user input for the objects

Tags: java, java-8

Question : Create a two objects of class Employee and check both are same or diffrent

Below code gives an error : **Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException**

**Only object e1 accepts values**

```
 class Employee {
        String name;
        int age;
        char gender;

        public Employee() {
                super();
        }
        public Employee (String name, int age, char gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public char getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
        public void setGender(char gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
}
public class Source {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Employee e1 = new Employee();
    
            //e1.name = sc.nextLine();
            //e1.age = sc.nextInt();
            //e1.gender = sc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(e1.name+" "+e1.age+" "+e1.gender);
            Employee e2 = new Employee();
            //e2.name = sc.nextLine();
            //e2.age = sc.nextInt();
            //e2.gender = sc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(e2.name+" "+e2.age+" "+e2.gender);
    
            boolean isSame = e1.equals(e2);
            if(e1.equals(e2)) {
                System.out.println("Same");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Different");
            }
       }
}
```

How to take user input or input from keyboard for objects e1 and e2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your Employee and Source classes, take a look.

```
public class Source {

Scanner sc = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Source source = new Source();
    
    Employee e1 = source.getEmployee();
    Employee e2 = source.getEmployee();

    if(e1.equals(e2)) {
        System.out.println("Same");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Different");
    }
    
    source.closeScanner();
}

public Source() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public void closeScanner() {
    sc.close();
}

public Employee getEmployee() {

    Employee e = new Employee();

    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    e.name = sc.next();

    System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
    e.age = sc.nextInt();


    System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
    e.gender = sc.next().charAt(0);


    System.out.println(e.getName() + " " + e.getAge() + " " + e.getGender());

    return e;
}
```

}

```
public class Employee {

String name;
int age;
char gender;

public Employee() {
        super();
        int age = -1;
}
public Employee (String name, int age, char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + age;
    result = prime * result + gender;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (age != other.age)
        return false;
    if (gender != other.gender)
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Please note that I've added the following two methods

> public int hashCode()

and

> public boolean equals(Object obj)

to make it possible to compare the two instances of the employee object

Comment: It's working thank you.. do we have any simple way to solve this because I am a beginner

Comment: If you are asking about simplifying the "equals" and "hashCode" methods then please know that IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ Idea can generate those two methods for you automatically. I've generated them in Eclipse IDE.
They can be a bit complex for beginners and yes you can simplify them also but I would suggest you to read a little about them, when you can, to understand their purpose.